# Printing a summary entered by user in textearea in PHP

Tags: php, string

i have a form textearea field where a user enter a summary like:

> il est poli comej hhh kkbkbkbkb
>   jbbbjbjblb ljlllbbblblb bnlbggkgkgkjg
>   lkjhhlhlhlhlhlh fin.

I would like to output this in two lines ending with '...' without printing all like

> il est poli
>
> comej hhh
>
> kkbbkbkb jbbbjblb...

How to handle this in php ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'asdf asdf sadf asdf asf asdf asdf asdf sfd';
$cut_length = 100;
if (strlen($str) > $cut_length)
  $str = substr($str, 0, $cut_length) .'...';

$line_length = 50;
$str_words = explpode(' ', $str);
$len = 0;
$str = '';
foreach ($str_words as $word) {
  $str .= $word . ' ';
  $len += strlen($word);
  if ($len >= $line_length) {
    $str .= '<br/>';
    $len = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: what about two (of three) lines?

Comment: You should replace your 100 in the if with $cut_length so no text goes missing when that's increased. Also $cut is undefined and should be $cut_length also.

Comment: Should $line_length be half of $cut_length? i.e. $cut_length / 2

Comment: @Alexander Varwijk
the question was 
>  in two lines 
therefore i declare max lrngth to be 100 sym and line length = 50. but if author need to divide enything into 2 lines than `$line_length = $cut_length / 2;`
in this example i want line length to be about 50 symbol. this allow you to divide text into several lines (however this can be done by css instead)

Comment: I meant to write shouldn't. I'm just saying you're hardcoding the line length and was offering an alternative. CSS would make more sense for the line cutt-off in general though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$summary = explode($textarea,' '); //split user input in words
echo $summary [0], ' ',$summary [1], ' ',$summary [2]; //print first 3 words
echo '<br>'; //newline
echo $summary [3], ' ',$summary [4]; //print 2 more words
echo '<br>'; //newline
echo $summary [5], ' ',$summary [6]; //print 2 more words
echo '...'; //dots
?>
```

This can be:

```
<?php
$summary = explode($textarea,' '); //split user input in words
echo $summary [0], ' ',$summary [1], ' ',$summary [2],'<br>',$summary [3], ' ',$summary [4],'<br>', $summary [5], ' ',$summary [6],'...';
?>
```

Comment: thankyou guys, thes methodes work well: wordwrap, explode... but now the probleme is when the user enter: 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'  without space i can't handle breakline !! somebody help pliz